# Toggle ng-click attribute

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a *span* with an *ng-click="..."* attribute. The *ng-click* slightly modifies the span's CSS within the DOM so that it is more *button-like*. Within my application I wish to toggle whether or not that *span* is clickable or not. I can make the *ng-click* not do anything easy enough but what I would prefer is to just remove/disable the attribute altogether. This is to avoid all "buttonizing" that the *ng-click* does to the element. It would also be nice if the attribute were re-enabled if the **clickable** variable becomes true again.

I would like a solution that avoids using *$scope.$watch*es because my application is pretty large and watches are slow.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can have two spans with and without `ng-click` attribute and based on that clickable variable you control those two spans with `ng-if` or `ng-show`.

Comment: That is a good idea thanks!

Comment: I was about to give the same solution as @Achu. Please submit it as answer so the question can be checked as answered.

Comment: @MaartenBicknese Thanks for you suggestion. I did as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can have two spans with and without `ng-click` attribute and based on that clickable variable you control those two spans with `ng-if` or `ng-show`

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution suggested by to [Achu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3826160/achu)!

Just use two spans rather than toggle the attribute on a single span.

```
<span ng-if="clickable" ng-click="...">Click me!</span>
<span ng-if="!clickable">Cant click me!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were in such a situation, I would not try to `enable` or `disable` `ng-click` attribute. Rather, I would use some flag variable with the `$scope` to see if click function should perform its functionality or not like in your controller you have a method like

```
$scope.spanClick = function(){
    if(!$scope.shouldClick){
       return;//simply do nothing       

    }
    //Do button click logic
}
```

Comment: I have done that. What I was trying to avoid was the small amount of 'button-like' css that the ng-click does to the element.